# The Gnome Control center (system settings ) app on ubuntu 20.04 crashes when I try to change network settings like : DNS or ipv6

Tags: network-manager, crash, system-settings

Basically the title says it all if you need more info tell me I really hope I can fix this im guessing it’s because of the network manager but I’m new to Linux and really don’t know

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out all i need to do is type this in the terminal :

“sudo apt install network-manager-gnome”

Hope this helps someone else :